# Using TextBoxFor in a Partial in ServiceStack Razor

Tags: .net, servicestack

I'd like to use the TextBoxFor helper in a partial that inherits from ViewPage but it fails silently with no error.

In the Rockstar Project I created a partial like this:

```
@inherits ViewPage<Rockstar>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
```

And inserted this line into Rockstars.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("Partial")
```

Should this work?